# How to detect the mouse event is vertical scrolling or horizontal scrolling

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, nsscrollview

How to detect the mouse event is vertical scrolling or horizon scrolling in NSScrollView?

thanks.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just care about horizon scrolling event for self view. the vertical scrolling event pass to enclosing ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create custom scrollbars for NSScrollView's horizontal and vertical scrollers.
2. Add a property called "isScrolling" or something similar to the custom scrollers.
3. Override trackKnob: on the scrollers, set the property to true. Call *[super trackKnob:aEvent]* and set property to false.
4. Use the property to determine if a scrollbar is being used.